# Moving table view cells down without moving tableview's origin

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I want to be able to move/shift the group of UITableViewCells in the UITableView downward, without scrolling the tableView, and without moving the entire tableview downward.  The desired effect is that there is an amount of whitespace above the table view cells after they're placed in the table view, and when the user scrolls down through the table view, the white space is covered by the cells.

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear.

Comment: Okay I tried to make it more understandable. Let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that a UITableView is a subclass of [UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIScrollView).

And that UIScrollView have this property.

> **contentInset**
>   The distance that the content view is inset from the enclosing scroll view.
>   @property(nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets contentInset
>   **Discussion**
>   Use this property to add to the scrolling area around the content. The unit of size is points. The default value is UIEdgeInsetsZero.

I don't fully understand what you are trying to do, so I just hope that this is what you are looking for.

---

After Question was Edited

Add an empty cell where you want it to be and adjust it's size when needed.
You will need to make some try about doing it animated (using insert and reloadCell) or using the `reloadData` option of the tableView to get the visual you want.

Comment: I think the contentInset is what I was looking for. If I change the content inset to be (size, 0, 0, 0) then change the content offset to be (-size, 0, 0, 0) it appears to start the cells where I want them with the correct amount of whitespace, as well as bounce where I need it to.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tableView header and adjust its size. After changing its size, call:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

If you want to animate the size change, try calling:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

After changing the header's size.

**EDIT 1:**

As opposed to a table view header, you could use a static cell as mentioned in the other answer. To animate the size change, use the steps above. Change the size in:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```